Magnolia CMS template code in publisher different with the author
So I have two instances. One is for author and one is for publisher.
I have a jar file which consists of templates, components, and backend services.
This jar is deployed into each instance's WEB-INF/lib folder.
Someday, I have to change the template in my jar. So, I code it, build into the jar, and deployed to those instances.
I saw changes in the author instance. But when I go to my publisher url, the template hasn't updated. I tried to publish a page from author, hoping maybe it will refreshed or published the updated template from author into the public.
But it is not updated.
The only way that can do the job is overwriting the template in Author Resource file then publish it.
Is there any way beside overwriting the template from the Author?
Why is this happening?

Did you redeploy a whole webapp or just uploaded the new jar to existing instances?
I suggest you check the following:

Compare the WEB-INF/lib folders on both instances to ensure you didn't leave the old copy of the jar file in place.
Check the configured modules directory to ensure you don't have the same template deployed via one of the light modules.
Unpublish the edited template in the resources app. As long as it remains published, it will always override what is coming from the filesystem.


I just upload the jar into the webapps/magnoliaAuthor(or Public)/WEB-INF/bin, then restart the tomcat.
I always got 403 when try to unpublish or delete the override template. Is it because my role in author?

if your attempt to unpublished ends with 403, then this is most likely because the public instance doesn't recognise your author as valid. Does publishing actually work for you?
